# Unable to start node js server when wanted to tail a file

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have written a very simple node js + react js app. The purpose is to tail a file and send to react for display and keep updating it for generating sequence diagram using react-sequence-diagram. 
Now my server's `index.js` looks like:

```
const express = require('express');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

// Gives error (option 1): Doesn't work
// const Tail = require('tail-file');
// tail = new Tail('/home/roshan/syslog');
// const mytail = new Tail("/home/roshan/syslog", data => {
//     app.use(express.static('dist'));
//     app.get('/api/getUsername', (req, res) => {
//         res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'connection': 'keep-alive'} );
//         res.write(data);
//         res.end();
//     });

// Gives error (option 2): Doesn't work
// Tail = require('tail').Tail;
// tail = new Tail('/home/roshan/syslog');
// var options= {separator: /[\r]{0,1}\n/, fromBeginning: true, fsWatchOptions: {}, follow: true}
//     tail.on("line", function(data) {
//         console.log(data);
//         app.use(express.static('dist'));
//         app.get('/api/getUsername', (req, res) => {
//             res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'connection': 'keep-alive'});
//             res.write(data);
//             res.end();
//         });
//     tail.watchEvent.call(tail, "change");
//     tail.on("error", function(error) {
//         console.log('ERROR: ', error);
//         });

// only this works
fs.readFile('/home/roshan/syslog', "utf8",  function(err, data) {
    app.use(express.static('dist'));
    app.get('/api/getUsername', (req, res) => {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'connection': 'keep-alive'} );
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });


    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${process.env.PORT || 8080}!`));
  });
```

My setting in `webpack.config.js` about the proxy connection

```
  devServer: {
    port: 9000,
    open: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api/': {
      target: "http://[::1]:8080",
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false
      }
    }
  },
```

and the client `app.js` looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './app.css';
import ReactImage from './react.png';
import SequenceDiagram from 'react-sequence-diagram';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = { time:Date.now(), results: ""};

  componentDidMount() {    
    fetch('/api/getUsername')
      .then(res => res.text()
      .then((text) => {
        this.setState({ results: text });
      })
      )
      this.interval = setInterval(() => this.setState({ time: Date.now()}), 5000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {

    const options = {
      theme: 'simple'
    };

    const input = this.state.results
    return (
      <div>
    <SequenceDiagram input={input} options={options}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

With this whenever I use option 1 or 2 I am getting the error:

[1] ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
[1] [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/getUsername from localhost:9000 to http://[::1]:8080 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

What is wrong am I doing? I am staring the server as `npm run dev` and the boilerplate is taken from here https://github.com/crsandeep/simple-react-full-stack/tree/master/src/server

Comment: You may check this issue https://github.com/saikat/react-apollo-starter-kit/issues/20

Comment: @michael: I tried some fixes from there but still no success. The main question is why the 3rd one works.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this but it's not the best, you have to use websocket to push the data from file to the front end app,

```
 const express = require('express');
 const os = require('os');
 const fs = require('fs');
 const app = express();
 const Tail = require('tail-file');

 let data = ""; 

  app.use(express.static('dist'));
  app.get('/api/getUsername', (req, res) => {
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'connection': 'keep-alive'} );
     res.write(data);
     res.end();
     //   data= "";  // un comment this line if you don't need old data
 });

  const mytail = new Tail('/home/roshan/syslog', line => {
     data = data + line ; 
  });



app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => 
  console.log(`Listening on port ${process.env.PORT || 8080}!`));
});
```